# Javascript D3 CSS, page doensn't work without error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

As the Title states, I have a stock drop-down menu with some CSS layout and stuff. The problem is, as soon as I add my D3 code into the page, the drop-down menu stops working. They only relate to each other in one function and I really don't get why they affect each other.

Javascript:

```
<script src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function passvars(countryname, number){
var country = countryname;
var diagramvalue = number;
if (diagramvalue === 0){

}
else if(diagramvalue === 1){

                //Geef waardes van marge, breedte en hoogt, hier wordt later weer naar terug gerefereerd
            var margin = {top: 20, right: 220, bottom: 80, left: 70},
                width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                //Geeft breedte van de bars op de x-as
            var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .5);

                //Y-as, met hoogte
            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .rangeRound([height, 0]);

                //Geeft kleuren van de bars
            var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#261758", "#605292", "#877CB0"]);
                //vooraf gegeven waardes waar x en y as moeten komen
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

                //SVG geeft hoeveelheid scherm wat getoont wordt
            var svg2 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
              .append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

              cachedSvg = svg2;

                //Inladen csv van site, daarna elke waarde van Periods oproepen
            d3.csv("http://arnoutdael.github.io/latvia.csv", function(error, dataset) {

                //Data die moet worden weergeven
              var data = [];
                      for (i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
                        var Countryyears = {
                            Periods : dataset[i].Periods,
                            "Immigratie 0 tot 20 jaar" : dataset[i].immigration,
                            "Immigratie 20 tot 65 jaar" : dataset[i].immigration25,
                            "Immigratie 65 jaar en ouder" : dataset[i].immigration65
                        }
                        //Nieuwe data voor array
                        data.push(Countryyears); 
                    }
              color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Periods"; }));

              //Verkrijgen alle values
              data.forEach(function(d) {
                var y0 = 0;
                d.values = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
                d.total = d.values[d.values.length - 1].y1;
              });

              x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Periods; }));
              y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

                //Tekst van x-as
                svg2.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")  
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                    .attr("dy", ".15em")
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "rotate(-65)" 
                    })
                svg2.append("text")
                    .attr("x", 650)
                    .attr("y", 550)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Jaren van immigratie");

              //Tekst van y-as
              svg2.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .call(yAxis)
                .append("text")
                  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                  .attr("y", 9)
                  .attr("dy", ".71em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text("Hoeveelheid immigranten");

              //Geeft Periodstallen
              var Periods = svg2.selectAll(".Periods")
                  .data(data)
                .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "g")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Periods) + ",0)"; });

              //Creëert de bars
              Periods.selectAll("rect")
                  .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
                .enter().append("rect")
                  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
                  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

              //Legenda tekst
              var legend = svg2.selectAll(".legend")
                  .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
                .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "legend")
                  .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

              //Creërt bars van legenda (kleuren)     
              legend.append("rect")
                  .attr("x", width + 120)
                  .attr("width", 18)
                  .attr("height", 18)
                  .style("fill", color);

              //Legenda tekst positie     
              legend.append("text")
                  .attr("x", width + 110)
                  .attr("y", 9)
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text(function(d) { return d; });});
 }
 else if(diagramvalue === 2){

 }
 else{

}
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<h1 class="title">Charts</h1>
<ul>
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Circle Diagram <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Bar Diagram <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Albania', 1)">Albania</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Armenia', 1)">Armenia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Austria', 1)">Austria</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Azerbaijan', 1)">Azerbaijan</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Belgium', 1)">Belgium</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Bulgaria', 1)">Bulgaria</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Croatia', 1)">Croatia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Cyprus', 1)">Cyprus</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Czech Republic', 1)">Czech Republic</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Denmark', 1)">Denmark</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Estonia', 1)">Estonia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Finland', 1)">Finland</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('France', 1)">France</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Georgia', 1)">Georgia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Germany', 1)">Germany</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Greece', 1)">Greece</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Hungary', 1)">Hungary</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Italy', 1)">Italy</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Latvia', 1)">Latvia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Luxembourg', 1)">Luxembourg</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Norway', 1)">Norway</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Poland', 1)">Poland</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Portugal', 1)">Portugal</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Romenia', 1)">Romenia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Russia', 1)">Russia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Slovakia', 1)">Slovakia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Slovenia', 1)">Slovenia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Spain', 1)">Spain</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Sweden', 1)">Sweden</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Switzerland', 1)">Switzerland</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Turkey', 1)">Turkey</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('United Kingdom', 1)">United Kingdom</button></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Line Diagram <i class="icon-arrow"></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><button onclick="passvars('Albania', 2)">Albania</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Armenia', 2)">Armenia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Austria', 2)">Austria</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Azerbaijan', 2)">Azerbaijan</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Belgium', 2)">Belgium</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Bulgaria', 2)">Bulgaria</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Croatia', 2)">Croatia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Cyprus', 2)">Cyprus</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Czech Republic', 2)">Czech Republic</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Denmark', 2)">Denmark</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Estonia', 2)">Estonia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Finland', 2)">Finland</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('France', 2)">France</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Georgia', 2)">Georgia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Germany', 2)">Germany</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Greece', 2)">Greece</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Hungary', 2)">Hungary</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Italy', 2)">Italy</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Latvia', 2)">Latvia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Luxembourg', 2)">Luxembourg</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Norway', 2)">Norway</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Poland', 2)">Poland</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Portugal', 2)">Portugal</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Romenia', 2)">Romenia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Russia', 2)">Russia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Slovakia', 2)">Slovakia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Slovenia', 2)">Slovenia</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Spain', 2)">Spain</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Sweden', 2)">Sweden</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Switzerland', 2)">Switzerland</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('Turkey', 2)">Turkey</button></li>
   <li><button onclick="passvars('United Kingdom', 2)">United Kingdom</button></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
            @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900");
            @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
            body {
              font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial;
              font-size: 16px;
            }


            *, *:before, *:after {
              -webkit-border-sizing: border-box;
              -moz-border-sizing: border-box;
              border-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .container {
              width: 350px;
              margin: 10px auto;
              float: left;
              padding-left: 10px;
            }
            .container > ul {
              list-style: none;
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0 0 20px 0;
            }

            .title {
              font-family: 'Pacifico';
              font-weight: normal;
              font-size: 40px;
              text-align: left;
              line-height: 1.4;
              color: #2980B9;
            }

            .dropdown a {
              text-decoration: none;
            }
            .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"] {
              position: relative;
              display: block;
              color: white;
              background: #2980B9;
              -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
              box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #409ad5 inset, 0 -1px 0 #20638f inset;
              text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
              padding: 10px;
            }
            .dropdown [data-toggle="dropdown"]:hover {
              background: #2c89c6;
            }
            .dropdown .icon-arrow {
              position: absolute;
              display: block;
              font-size: 0.7em;
              color: #fff;
              top: 14px;
              right: 10px;
            }
            .dropdown .icon-arrow.open {
              -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
              -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
              -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
              transform: rotate(-180deg);
              -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
              -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
              -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
              transition: transform 0.6s;
            }
            .dropdown .icon-arrow.close {
              -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
              -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
              -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
              transform: rotate(0deg);
              -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.6s;
              -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s;
              -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s;
              transition: transform 0.6s;
            }
            .dropdown .icon-arrow:before {
              content: '\25BC';
            }
            .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
              max-height: 0;
              overflow: hidden;
              list-style: none;
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
            }
            .dropdown .dropdown-menu li {
              padding: 0;
            }
            .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a {
              display: block;
              color: #6e6e6e;
              background: #EEE;
              -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
              box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d4d4d4 inset;
              text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
              padding: 10px 10px;
            }
            .dropdown .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
              background: #f6f6f6;
            }
            .dropdown .show, .dropdown .hide {
              -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
              -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
              -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
              transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            }
            .dropdown .show {
              display: block;
              max-height: 9999px;
              -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
              -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
              -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
              transform: scaleY(1);
              animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
              -moz-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-animation: showAnimation 0.5s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
              -o-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
              -webkit-transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
              transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
            }
            .dropdown .hide {
              max-height: 0;
              -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
              -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
              -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
              transform: scaleY(0);
              animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
              -moz-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
              -webkit-animation: hideAnimation 0.4s ease-out;
              -moz-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
              -o-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
              -webkit-transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
              transition: max-height 0.6s ease-out;
            }

            @keyframes showAnimation {
              0% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                transform: scaleY(0.1);
              }
              40% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                transform: scaleY(1.04);
              }
              60% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                transform: scaleY(1.04);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                transform: scaleY(1.02);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
              }
            }
            @-moz-keyframes showAnimation {
              0% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                transform: scaleY(0.1);
              }
              40% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                transform: scaleY(1.04);
              }
              60% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                transform: scaleY(1.04);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                transform: scaleY(1.02);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
              }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes showAnimation {
              0% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
                transform: scaleY(0.1);
              }
              40% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                transform: scaleY(1.04);
              }
              60% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.04);
                transform: scaleY(1.04);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                transform: scaleY(1.02);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
              }
            }
            @keyframes hideAnimation {
              0% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
              }
              60% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                transform: scaleY(1.02);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
                transform: scaleY(0);
              }
            }
            @-moz-keyframes hideAnimation {
              0% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
              }
              60% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                transform: scaleY(1.02);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
                transform: scaleY(0);
              }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes hideAnimation {
              0% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
                transform: scaleY(1);
              }
              60% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
                transform: scaleY(0.98);
              }
              80% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
                transform: scaleY(1.02);
              }
              100% {
                -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
                -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
                -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
                transform: scaleY(0);
              }
            }
```

Comment: is there anything in your javascript console regarding errors?

Comment: No, nothing at all... That's why I don't get what's going wrong.

Comment: i have a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/n7pz5eL5/1/
Aside from missing a single 'var' in a `for` loop, your code looks fine and seems to be working as it should.

Comment: i seem to be missing the javascript code for your dropdown menu though.

Comment: It drops down by using css. Still the drop-down doesn't actually drop down?

Comment: No, and it won't either way, with or without d3. from what i gather from the hyperlinks with `data-toggle="dropdown"`  is that your menu might depend on bootstrap. is that correct?

Comment: No it does not, it did drop down like 30 minutes ago, untill I added my code... from then on it stopped working.

Comment: check if "dropdown" class is reserved by d3. Try renaming it to "list_dropdown"